# Good practice for error messages when checking multiple parameters

Tags: scala, error-handling, parameters, require

My problem:

- I have a function with two file paths that are both required to start with `'/'`.
- I struggled with finding a simple solution to tell the caller of the function precisely what went wrong if the requirement failed.
- For example, if only one of the paths is wrong, should I say the first file parameter was wrong or the parameter with name `aFile`? It was more complicated than I thought.

My solution:

- After failing to give back the incorrect paths in a simple and clear manner, I settled with the following solution, where I give back all paths, because it was simple, gave clear information and is easy to adapt to more paths. (Also it was shorter than using an `if-else` statement):

```
/** ...
  * @param i        Some number...
  * @param aFile    Path of AData file to use (e.g. "/dir/a.csv")
  * @param anyPath  Random text...
  * @param bFile    Path of BData file to use (e.g. "/bData.csv")
  */
def f(i: Int, aFile: String, anyPath: String, bFile: String): Unit = {
  val s = List(aFile, bFile)
  require(!s.exists(!_.startsWith("/")),
    "Paths aFile and bFile must start with '/', but List(aFile, bFile) was: " + s)
}


val a = "/adf"
val b = "asdf"
f(1, a, "eee", b)
// IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
// Paths aFile and bFile must start with '/', but List(aFile, bFile) was: List(/adf, asdf)
```

Are there suggestions or a good practice to handle such a case better?

Comment: Not throwing exceptions, and not using `require` would be a good start. `Either` with ADT of possible errors on `Left`, for synchronous error handling. `for` comprehension to combine results. If async, then there are advances solutions, but that should be enough for now. `if`-`else` really isn't that bad when you remember that if-else is an expression and not a statement that needs `return`. Here pattern matching would also work.

Comment: From the standpoint of language constructs/patterns to use, and type safety, that helps me. Yes, if-else is really not that bad and actually easy to understand, easy code can be longer (like Linux Torvalds says in his kernel style guide btw ;). The core for me in this question is still the problem of telling which parameter went wrong. For example, there is no binding from aFile to "aFile" such that i need to update the message when I change the name of the parameter. Ok, this is solved by proper refactoring... But still, I think it's an important topic to think about good error messages.